# relative length of line in word

Tags: vba, line, ms-word

I want to calculate the length of the line, relative to a full line, using VBA. I mean that the last line in the paragraph (when the text is justified) is not full, so I want to calculate the percent that the text fills out of a full line.

I want to calculate the physical size, not the number of characters.

I found that question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ee2ccb3-6611-4c39-bbfe-ff078d847df8/microsoft-word-length-of-last-line-via-vba?forum=isvvba), but anyone actually answered...

Comment: Technically, this question is "too broad" since you don't provide any real research that you've done. The question in Word is not simple, however, so I've provided some basic code that will work in an "ordinary" situation. Note that my code only gives you the lenght of the line and the possible width between the margins of the page. I don't do the calculation for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not straight-forward in Word since a "line" is dynamic - it breaks wherever Word thinks it should when it lays out the page. Therefore, only way to determine a "line" is to use the Selection object.

```
Sub LengthOfLine()
    Dim sel As word.Selection
    Dim pgSetup As word.PageSetup
    Dim iStart, iEnd As Long, dblWidth As Double
    Dim dblLineLen As Double

    Set pgSetup = sel.Sections(1).PageSetup
    dblWidth = pgSetup.PageWidth - pgSetup.LeftMargin - pgSetup.RightMargin
    Set sel = Selection
    'Get to the front of the line and determine its position
    sel.MoveEnd wdLine, -1
    iStart = sel.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
    'Get to the end of the line and determine its position
    sel.MoveStart wdLine, 1
    sel.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    iEnd = sel.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
    'Calculate the length of the line
    dblLineLen = PointsToCentimeters(iEnd - iStart)

    Debug.Print "line length: " & dblLineLen
    Debug.Print "line space remaining: " & PointsToCentimeters(dblWidth) - dblLineLen
End Sub
```